# C Program to convert lowercase to uppercase char array without using other functions available in the C standard library

Tags: c, pointers, makefile, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to replace all lowercase letters by their uppercase counterpart without using other functions available in the C standard library and using pointers.
I have my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "upper1.h"

int main() {
    
        char string[] = "HelloWorld";
        int arraySize = sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0]);
        printf("String before transformation: ");
        int i;
        for (i= 0; i< arraySize; i++) {
            printf("%c", string[i]); //prints array information
        } 
        printf("\n");
        
        char *str = string; //pointer that points to the array
        
        upper1(str);
        
        printf("String before transformation: ");
        int j;
        for (j= 0; j< arraySize; j++) {
            printf("%c", string[i]); //prints array information
        } 
        printf("\n");
        
        return 0;
}
```

And I have my function code file:

```
void upper1(char *str) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(*str >= 65 + 32 && *str <= 90 + 32) { //65+32 is "a" and 90+32 is "z"
            *str = *str - 32;
        }
        str++;// skips one position of the array
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run I get:

gcc -g -Wall -c upper1.c -o upper1.o
gcc -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
gcc upper1.o main.o -o ex04
./ex04
String before transformation: HelloWorld
String before transformation: �����������

Instead of

gcc -g -Wall -c upper1.c -o upper1.o
gcc -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
gcc upper1.o main.o -o ex04
./ex04
String before transformation: HelloWorld
String before transformation: HELLOWORLD

(I have a file "upper1.h" but that's correct only with: `void upper1(char *str);`)

Comment: Not related to the problem but you should really not use magic numbers in your code. If you mean `a`you should use `a` and not `65+32`. Magic numbers make things much harder to read.

Comment: `printf("%c", string[i]); //prints array information` The loop is using `j` as counter.

Comment: BTW: `arraySize` includes the terminating 0-byte. You should use `strlen` to get the correct length.

Comment: In that case I'm using <string.h> library and I can't. It's an exercise rule. Anyway I solved it. It was just a mistake in "main.c" about my "for" cicle using the wrong index ('i' instead of 'j'). Anyway I'm using this to prevent of using magic numbers:
```
void upper1(char *str) {
 while(*str != '\0') {
  if(*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z') {
   *str = *str - 32;
  }
  str++;
 }
}
```

Comment: You could use your own `strlen` version. Or you could just decrease `arraySize` by one to skip the 0 byte.

Comment: How can I use my own  `strlen` ?

Comment: You write a function that counts the letters until you reach a `0`. You should use a different name, of course.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will not use this time, but next time definitely. Thanks.

Comment: It's not true that `64` is `a`.  `65` is `A`.  See for example http://www.asciitable.com/ To avoid these errors use the character code `'A'` not decimal `65`.  And ditto for `'Z'` etc.  Also it's pretty bogus that your `upper1()` function hard-codes the length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `i` in your second loop instead of `j`.

```
printf("String before transformation: ");
int j;
for (j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
    printf("%c", string[j]); // use 'j' instead of 'i'
}
```

You can avoid a typo like this in the future by declaring your loop counter inside the for-loop. This ensures the counter is only accessible within the scope of the loop and can't be reused in another loop:

```
printf("String before transformation: ");
for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
    printf("%c", string[j]);
}
```